# onchange select box

Tags: javascript, dom

Say we have 2 different select boxes with the same number of options:

```
<select id="box1">
<option value="1" >1</option>
<option value="2" >2</option>
</select>

<select id="box2">
<option value="3" >3</option>
<option value="4" >4</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible when we select the first box to select the same option number in the second box automatically? Without jQuery if possible.

UPDATE: the values of 2 boxes are different! When we select the first value of box1 the box 2's value will automatically would be 3! and so on...

Comment: When you say without jquery, do you mean specifically jquery, or javascript? Because anything that is possible with jquery is possible with javascript (as jquery is just a framework for javascript)

Comment: when I say without jquery I mean I dont have jquery framework on the page. by the way i edited the q, as some of you just simply setting the same value to the 2nd box.

Comment: Just use `<select id="box1" onChange="box2.value=box1.value">` See answer with more details....

Comment: Fahim Parkar, the boxes values are different. check the Q again, I updated it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.  Add an onChange property to the first select, then use it to call a javascript function you have written elsewhere.

```
<select id="box1" onChange="changeBox2(this.selectedIndex);">
<option value="1" >1</option>
<option value="2" >2</option>
</select>

<select id="box2">
<option value="1" >1</option>
<option value="2" >2</option>
</select>
```

[W3 Schools JavaScript Events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp)

[Example on Accessing SELECT properties in JS](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_option_index)

Comment: Nearly, two months later, And I'm sitting at two up, two down votes with the answer having been accepted.  Neither of the people who saw fit to downvote mentioned why.  Why?

Comment: It's probably because of the cult-like hatred that some people have of W3 Schools.  There are those who simply downvote on the basis of seeing any link to W3 Schools - I wouldn't take it personally.

Comment: I think your down-voters are attached to `eventListeners` over inline function calls.

Answer (score 3):

A javascript snippet code:

```
var box1=document.getElementById("box1");
box1.onchange=function (){
    document.getElementById("box2").value=box1.value;
}
```

Comment: +1 for reference caching and beating me to the answer by two whole minutes... quick posts is an art I am yet to master :)

Comment: obviously I dont need to set the value of the 2nd box the same as the first(they are different). It was just an example

Answer (score 3):

The following JS would work:

```
document.getElementById("box1").onchange = function(){
    document.getElementById("box2").value = this.value;
};
```

Not the most elegant code I've written but gets you what you need. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XZRKS/

Answer (score 1):

Hope below is what you want...

```
<html>
<body>
<select id="box1" onChange="box2.value=box1.value">
<option value="1" >1</option>
<option value="2" >2</option>
<option value="3" >3</option>
<option value="4" >4</option>
<option value="5" >5</option>
<option value="6" >6</option>
<option value="7" >7</option>
</select>

<select id="box2"  onChange="box1.value=box2.value">
<option value="1" >1</option>
<option value="2" >2</option>
<option value="3" >3</option>
<option value="4" >4</option>
<option value="5" >5</option>
<option value="6" >6</option>
<option value="7" >7</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var box1 = document.getElementById("box1");
var box2 = document.getElementById("box2");
box1.addEventListener("change", function(e){
    var val = parseInt(this.value);
    box2.querySelector("option:nth-child("+val+")").selected = true;
}, false);
```

This will only work in Gecko/Mozilla only
For IE use onChange instead of change and attachEvent instead of addEventListener, for more info visit 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

for information on querySelector see this link 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#box1").on('change',function(){
  document.getElementById("box2").value = this.value;
  console.log($("#box2").val());
});
$("#box2").on('change',function(){
  document.getElementById("box1").value = this.value;
});
```

```html
<select id="box1">
<option value="1" >1</option>
<option value="2" >2</option>
</select>

<select id="box2">
<option value="1" >1</option>
<option value="2" >2</option>
</select>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it's simple in javascript. just one line.

```
function ch(){
  document.getElementById("box2").value = document.getElementById("box1").value ;
}
```

you can call `ch()` on `onchange` event of `box2`