# Javascript change input value when select option is selected

Tags: javascript, html, input, show-hide

I am very new to javascript. So i have a select option and an input field. What i want to achieve is to have the value of the input field change when i select a particular option. This is what i have tried:

```
First Name: <input type="text" value="colors">

<select name="">
   <option>Choose Database Type</option>
   <option onclick="myFunction(g)>green</option>
   <option onclick="myFunction(r)>red</option>
   <option onclick="myFunction(o)>orange</option>
   <option onclick="myFunction(b)>black</option>
</select>

<script>
function myFunction(g) {
    document.getElementById("myText").value = "green";
}
function myFunction(r) {
    document.getElementById("myText").value = "red";
}
function myFunction(o) {
    document.getElementById("myText").value = "orange";
}
function myFunction(b) {
    document.getElementById("myText").value = "black";
}
</script>
```

Comment: 1. Please think about the DRY principle. 2. You have no element with an ID of "text". 3. You're passing in params which are undefined. 4. You don't use them.

Comment: Without trying to sound too mean/harsh, I would suggest you go off and follow some basic JavaScript tutorials first before asking questions like this as if you knew even a small amount of JS you'd know the problem.

Comment: @evolutionxbox 5. his functions are named the same and so are overwriting the previous ones, which is the main issue imo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onchange select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764897/onchange-select-box)

Comment: @George true. It was more order of first notice than anything...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A few things:

You should use the `onchange` function, rather than `onclick` on each individual option.

Use a `value` attribute on each option to store the data, and use an instance of `this` to assign the change (or `event.target`)

You have no ID on your text field

You're missing the end quote for your `onclick` function

```
<select name="" onchange="myFunction(event)">
    <option disabled selected>Choose Database Type</option>
    <option value="Green">green</option>
    <option value="Red">red</option>
    <option value="Orange">orange</option>
    <option value="Black">black</option>
</select>
```

And the function:

```
function myFunction(e) {
    document.getElementById("myText").value = e.target.value
}
```

And add the ID

```
<input id="myText" type="text" value="colors">
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gasjv4hs/

Comment: Like i aforesaid, i'm very new to javascript. Thanks Alot for the explanation. It worked it out!

Comment: Please i tried to implement this on [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com) but it doesn't work. Do you have an idea how i can make it work?

Comment: @DanielC. - Sorry - I'm not very familiar with CKEditor - I'm guessing it has to do with the placement of the script - make sure the script is loaded after the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

More proper way is to put your JS code in  a different .js file and use Jquery as when you go further with your programming this is the proper way.

**Your HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="color" name="color">
<select name="" id="changeData">
<option>Choose Database Type</option>
<option data-value="green">green</option>
<option data-value="red">red</option>
<option data-value="orange">orange</option>
<option data-value="black">black</option>
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
```

**Your JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
$('#changeData').change(function(){
var color = $(this).val();
$('#color').val(color);
})
});
```

Also make sure that you have added Jquery Library to your Project. You can either download Jquery and add in your project folder OR also you can use CDN. in this example CDN is used.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a similar problem. In my case i was trying to change the minimum value of an input based on the value of an option in a select list. I tried to apply the above solutions but nothing worked. So i came with this, which can be applied to problems similar to this

HTML

```
<input id="colors" type="text" value="">

<select id="select-colors" name="" onchange="myFunction()">
   <option disabled selected>Choose Colour</option>
   <option value="green">green</option>
   <option value="red">red</option>
   <option value="orange">orange</option>
   <option value="black">black</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("select-colors").value;
document.getElementById("colors").value = x;
  }
```

This works by getting the value of the select with id "select-colors" on every change, assigning it into a variable "x" and inserting it into the input value with id "colors". This can be implemented in anyway based on your problem

Answer (score 0):

You create functions with same name multiple times.

Only last one will work.

the variables you pass `g,r,o,b` are undefined.

Don't add `onclick` to `option` add `onchange` to `select`.

Make use of `HTML5` `data-*` attribute

```js
function myFunction(element) {
  document.getElementById("myText").value = element;
}
```

```html
First Name: <input type="text" id="myText" value="colors">

<select name="" onchange="myFunction(this.value);">
   <option>Choose Database Type</option>
   <option data-value="green">green</option>
   <option data-value="red">red</option>
   <option data-value="orange">orange</option>
   <option data-value="black">black</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please i tried to implement this on [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com) but it doesn't work. Do you have an idea how i can make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve it this way.

`    First Name:

```
<select name="" onchange="myFunction()" id="selectID">
   <option>Choose Database Type</option>
   <option >green</option>
   <option >red</option>
   <option >orange</option>
  <option >black</option>
</select>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var selectItem = document.getElementByID('selectID').value;
     document.getElementByID('yourId').value = sekectItem;

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to achieve that:

```js
var select = document.getElementById('colorName');

function myFunction(event) {
  var color = 'No color selected';

  if (select.selectedIndex > 0) {
    color = select.item(select.selectedIndex).textContent;
  }
  
  document.getElementById('myText').value = color;
}

select.addEventListener('click', myFunction);

myFunction();
```

```html
First Name: <input type="text" id="myText">

<select id="colorName">
   <option>Choose Database Type</option>
   <option>green</option>
   <option>red</option>
   <option>orange</option>
   <option>black</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please i tried to implement this on [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com) but it doesn't work. Do you have an idea how i can make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like following.

```
<input type="text" name="color" id="color">
 <select name="" id="change_color">
    <option>Choose Database Type</option>
   <option >green</option>
     <option >red</option>
    <option >orange</option>
   <option >black</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {     
    $('#change_color').change(function(){
    var color = ($(this).val());
    $('#color').val(color);
    })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please i tried to implement this on [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com) but it doesn't work. Do you have an idea how i can make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Here is JS Code that worked for me

```
var selectYear = document.getElementById('select-year');
selectYear.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var selectedYear = document.getElementById('selected-year');
  selectedYear.innerHTML = selectYear.value;
});
```

Select Input ID: select-year
Text ID: selected-year

Code generated from Codex AI :)