# Change input value based on selected option error: is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the value of an input element (url) based on a selected 
option (facetselection):

```
<script src="external.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function facetselection(e) {
document.getElementById("ebscohosturl").value = e.target.value;
}
</script>

<input id="url" name="ebscohosturl" type="hidden" value="" />
<div id="facets">
  <select id="facetselection" onchange="facetselection(event)">
    <option id="nofacet" value="new_url" label="הכל">הכל</option>
    <option id="facetarticles" value="new_url2" label="מאמרים אקדמיים">מאמרים אקדמיים</option>
    <option id="facetbooks" value="new_url3" label="ספרים">ספרים</option>
    <option id="facetebooks" value="new_url4" label="ספרים אלקטרוניים">ספרים אלקטרוניים</option>
    <option id="facetthesis" value="new_url5" label="תזות">תזות</option>
    <option id="facetmaps" value="new_url6" label="מפות">מפות</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This is based on the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44679332/javascript-change-input-value-when-select-option-is-selected). I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript) solution.
I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: facetselection is not a function
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange
```

What am I missing? I defined the function in a script element, and I think the syntax is correct.

Comment: @Guillaume Georges
The mistake was in writing the code, it is not what caused the error.
In my code, the IDs are the same. I already corrected the OP, and the issue is still not resolved by the answers thus far.

Comment: The <script> tag is loaded right after I load an external javascript:
<script src="externaljs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  function facetselection(e) {
    document.getElementById("ebscohosturl").value = e.target.value;
  }
</script>

For sure that tag is not loaded for some reason, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: I also tried to add the function directly in the external javascript, but it didn't work either for some unknown reason.

Comment: It shows status 200 OK, so I assume it was loaded successfully

Comment: The answer worked with the parameters I requested - if I check the code snippet specifically, it works. But it doesn't work in my main code, I assume because the script element doesn't load for some reason, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174842/discussion-between-guillaume-georges-and-nimrod-yanai).

Comment: Ok, thank you. I am there. Didn't know the chat existed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why JS function name conflicts with element ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158238/why-js-function-name-conflicts-with-element-id)

Comment: The issue was spotted in chat. And it appears this is a duplicate. The OP flagged it.

Answer (score 4):

Your error comes from the fact that your function has the same name as your select id : facetselection. It happens because your select is in a form (which it wasn't in your original code example).

Rename either your function or your select id and you should be fine.

It's actually a duplicate of [Why JS function name conflicts with element ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158238/why-js-function-name-conflicts-with-element-id)
but I can't flag it.

Snippet with reproductible behaviour :

```js
function facetselection(e) {
  document.getElementById("url").value = e.target.value;
}
```

```html
<form>
<input id="url" name="ebscohosturl" type="text" value="" />
<div id="facets">
  <select id="facetselection" onchange="facetselection(event)">
    <option id="nofacet" value="new_url" label="הכל">הכל</option>
    <option id="facetarticles" value="new_url2" label="מאמרים אקדמיים">מאמרים אקדמיים</option>
    <option id="facetbooks" value="new_url3" label="ספרים">ספרים</option>
    <option id="facetebooks" value="new_url4" label="ספרים אלקטרוניים">ספרים אלקטרוניים</option>
    <option id="facetthesis" value="new_url5" label="תזות">תזות</option>
    <option id="facetmaps" value="new_url6" label="מפות">מפות</option>
  </select>
</div>
</form>
```

Corrected snippet

```js
function facetSelection(e) {
  document.getElementById("url").value = e.target.value;
}
```

```html
<form>
<input id="url" name="ebscohosturl" type="text" value="" />
<div id="facets">
  <select id="facetselection" onchange="facetSelection(event)">
    <option id="nofacet" value="new_url" label="הכל">הכל</option>
    <option id="facetarticles" value="new_url2" label="מאמרים אקדמיים">מאמרים אקדמיים</option>
    <option id="facetbooks" value="new_url3" label="ספרים">ספרים</option>
    <option id="facetebooks" value="new_url4" label="ספרים אלקטרוניים">ספרים אלקטרוניים</option>
    <option id="facetthesis" value="new_url5" label="תזות">תזות</option>
    <option id="facetmaps" value="new_url6" label="מפות">מפות</option>
  </select>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry, that is of course a mistake made by clipping my original code to just the relevant part. I corrected the original post. In my code the IDs were correct.

Comment: No, the mistake was when copying the code here, not in the original. In the original the IDs are the same :D I corrected the OP

Answer (score 2):

**EDITED**

You're input doesn't have the id you are currently looking for, it needs to change from

`<input id="url" name="ebscohosturl" type="text" value="" />`

to

`<input id="ebscohosturl" name="ebscohosturl" type="text" value="" />`

working example:

```
<script>
  function facetselection(e) {
    document.getElementById("ebscohosturl").value = e.target.value;
  }
</script>

<input id="ebscohosturl" name="ebscohosturl" type="hidden" value="" />
<div id="facets">
  <select id="facetselection" onchange="facetselection(event)">
    <option id="nofacet" value="new_url" label="הכל">הכל</option>
    <option id="facetarticles" value="new_url2" label="מאמרים אקדמיים">מאמרים אקדמיים</option>
    <option id="facetbooks" value="new_url3" label="ספרים">ספרים</option>
    <option id="facetebooks" value="new_url4" label="ספרים אלקטרוניים">ספרים אלקטרוניים</option>
    <option id="facetthesis" value="new_url5" label="תזות">תזות</option>
    <option id="facetmaps" value="new_url6" label="מפות">מפות</option>
  </select>
</div>`
```

Comment: This removed the error message, but the function is not working (the value does not change).

Comment: Fixed the answer

Comment: Sorry, that is of course a mistake (I changed the id in the original post. In the code itself it is correct, I simply changed the IDs when creating the post.

Comment: @NimrodYanai I have updated my answer with code this works in my testing.

Comment: Thanx. I can see that it works when I try to use only this code snippet, but I still get the error message when I try it in my main code (which is very strange).
But this indeed solved the issue, there must be something else interfering with the script element.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the value directly

also you are getting element by id but passing the input name

```js
function facetselection(e) {
  document.getElementById("url").value = e;
}
```

```html
<input id="url" name="ebscohosturl" type="text" value="" />
<div id="facets">
  <select id="facetselection" onchange="facetselection(this.value)">
    <option id="nofacet" value="new_url" label="הכל">הכל</option>
    <option id="facetarticles" value="new_url2" label="מאמרים אקדמיים">מאמרים אקדמיים</option>
    <option id="facetbooks" value="new_url3" label="ספרים">ספרים</option>
    <option id="facetebooks" value="new_url4" label="ספרים אלקטרוניים">ספרים אלקטרוניים</option>
    <option id="facetthesis" value="new_url5" label="תזות">תזות</option>
    <option id="facetmaps" value="new_url6" label="מפות">מפות</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This didn't work. Still getting the same error message.

Comment: i have changed the input type hidden to text so you can see its working