TYPO3 EXT:femanager show hidden textfield upon a specific selection with select field
I followed the example on how to extended femanager with my own select field ... (https://docs.typo3.org/p/in2code/femanager/7.3/en-us/Features/NewFields/Index.html)
I had a question answered, leading to this question: TYPO3 EXT:femanager extended with a select field
I have the user select a userType, and the last option is "other" and
if selected I'd like to show a textfield that permits the user to leave his own userType registered ...
How do I :

use the selected value as a condition in fluid
and how do I refresh the form when the selection is changed?


I think you will need some JS magic for that. You could pass the onChange atrribute to your viewhelpers additionalAttributes and trigger a JS function to show a textfield.

Maybe this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44679332/javascript-change-input-value-when-select-option-is-selected

@Mogens good suggestion only that 'onchange' is not available, and 'onclick' is not correct, do you know how to extend TYPO3 to accept 'onchange' in this viewhelper ?

I think best practise would be to define a classname like "js-usertype" or so. And then add an onChange-event to that class. You could start looking here how to do that: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange_addeventlistener . I prefer using jquery for such things. The JQuery manual is here: https://api.jquery.com/change/
